# How to do Datetime convertion

Tags: android, sql-server, json, datetime

This is the first time I work with MSSQL(not control by me) and also with the WebServices (also third party)

Anyway, I getting JSON Array return from them, and one of the return is Datetime. The return as below: (FieldName : DataReturn)
CreatedDateTime : **/Date(1474300800000+0800)/**

I'm try to google around but I think I don't have the right "Keyword", so I can't get any example/tutorial for this.

So in android studio, how can I convert/format the above to YYYY/MM/DD or DD/MM/YYY

Thanks

Comment: this is a timpestamp. google converting timestamp to date.

Comment: Using Joda Time, you can covert it to `DateTime` object using `DateTime dt = new DateTime(timestamp);` and then parse it to whatever format you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, timestamp equals to 1474300800000 . Here's how you can format that date:

```
    String timestamp = "/Date(1474300800000+0800)/";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();        
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

    cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.valueOf(timestamp.substring(6,19)).longValue());
    dateFormat.setCalendar(cal);

    String formatted = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Also, as I can see JSON data also contains TimeZone info (+0800 in your case). If you want to specifiy timezone for the Calendar object, here's how you do that:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0800") // Add "GMT" at the beginning.
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
```

Comment: i getting the return is "1974/09/03"
but inside the database is "2016-09-20 00:00:00.000"

Comment: i getting the return is "1974/09/03"
but inside the database is "2016-09-20 00:00:00.000"

Comment: String temp = mVar.replace("/Date(", "");
temp = temp.replace(")/","");
temp = temp.substring(0, 12);
long l = Long.parseLong(temp);

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date(l));
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String formatted = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());

Comment: I edited the answer. It should work, I tested it myself.